# Unable to reach Azure MySQL DB from AKS cluster

Tags: azure, azure-container-service, azure-aks

I recreated my AKS cluster because of a failure and the new cluster can not access the azure managed mysql instance.  I receive an UnknownHostException for the azure managed mysql instance when my containers start up.  The nodes apparently have access to the outside world because it deploys the containers from an external container registry.

**EDIT**

There is a firewall rule that is open to everything.  0.0.0.0 -> 255.255.255.255

**EDIT 2**

I have an azure postgresql database also and it is visible.

Comment: Did the previous installation have a firewall rule added to the db? and now you've changed addresses it can't connect

Comment: @MichaelB Updated the post to reflect the firewall rules